# Use VisualSVN and subclipse with svn protocol

Tags: svn, subclipse, visualsvn

I recently had to copy my repositories from my linux machine to a new Windows machine. I used VisualSVN to set up my repositories on the Windows machine..

Now I have some projects in eclipse that uses the subclipse plugin to connect to my old repo location.

I do understand that VisualSVN does not support the svn protocol. So my problem is how do i get old projects that use the svn protocol to connect to the repos on VisualSVN that seem to support only the http/https protocol..

Will I have to disconnect from my old repos in eclipse and share the project as a new one in VisualSVN?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can always just add the new repository URL and checkout fresh from the new server.  But aside from that, you should be able to Relocate the repository.  Go to the SVN Repositories view, and right-click on your repository.  There should be a Relocate option.  This will launch a wizard where you can enter the new URL of the repository.  It will also switch all of your existing checked out projects to point at the new repository.